# how to set a global property that set on when spring boot application start

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to set up some global variables that are accessible by multiple classes. Examples of these global variables would be things like some key(Strings)

I am fetching these variable from database and  variables would probably not change except when the program is re-compiled

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide much details so the answer will be generic too.

There basically are two approaches:

1. You could use the Java `Properties` class.

   ```
   public static final Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
   ```

   Initialize your `defaultProperties` from database at program start with `defaultProperties.put("name", value)`.

   Access your properties by `defaultProperties.get("name")`.
2. Write your own configuration class.

   ```
   class MyConfig
   {
     public final String SomeStringProperty;
     public final int SomeIntProperty;
     // Singleton
     public final static MyConfig instance = new MyConfig();

     private MyConfig()
     { // Init properties from database here.
     }
   }
   ```

   You might need some dependency injection pattern to initialize `MyConfig`, e.g. to establish the database connection.

Both methods are similar. The second one provides more type safety and prevents you from accidentally accessing a non existent property because of a typo in the property name. The first one in contrast can be made generic in a way that no code changes to the configuration code are required when new properties are added. Of course, you still have to write code that *accesses* the new property.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define a `@Component` class with field of type`Map` for these properties. Then populate it at the start of your application with information retrieved from database.

Then, whenever you want to use these properties inject these using `Spring Boot`'s DI mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this properties on application.properties file.You can use this properties all over on your project.
For example:I am using key for hit third-party .So I am taking key on my properties file.